# Tautological and logical consequence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In Herbert Enderton's book *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*, it is mentioned [see page 115] that $Pc$ is not a tautological consequence of $\forall xPx$ (when both are taken as sentence variables for propositional calculus) but $Pc$ is a logical consequence of $\forall xPx$.

Suppose we let variables $u$ and $v$ (belonging to $\{ 0,1 \}$) represent the truth values of $\forall xPx$ and $Pc$ respectively.

Now "$Pc$ is not a tautological consequence of $\forall xPx$ (and vice versa)" would be equivalent to saying that "variables $u$ and $v$ are independent of each other".
On the other hand, "$Pc$ is a logical consequence of $\forall xPx$" is equivalent to saying "variables $u$ and $v$ are not independent of each other" [in fact, it is saying ,"$u \le v$"].

Since both "$Pc$ is not a tautological consequence of $\forall xPx$" and 
"$Pc$ is a logical consequence of $\forall xPx$" are true, where is the flaw in the above reasoning?

Comment: AxPx is $\forall x Px$?

Comment: @ tetori: yes .

Comment: Presumably, Enderton is trying to make some point about the meanings of the two phrases, so it's going to be hard to answer this question if you don't edit Enderton's definitions into the question.

Comment: Do you mean $u \leq v$, or $u \Longleftarrow v$?

Comment: @shades:it is u less or equal v.

Answer (score 3):

To say that $B$ is a tautological consequence of $A$ is in effect to say that $B$ is a logical consequence of $A$ in virtue of the distribution of truth-functional connectives in $A$ and $B$ (as we might put it, $A$ entails $B$ by the truth-table test). That's why $Pc$ is not a tautological consequence of $\forall xPx$ -- certainly $\forall xPx$ logically entails $Pc$, but plainly not in virtue of the distribution of truth-functional connectives in the premiss and the conclusion.

The OP writes

> "$Pc$ is not a tautological consequence of $\forall xPx$  ( and vice versa )"would be equivalent to saying that "[the truth values of $Pc$ and $\forall xPx$] are independent of each other".

Not so. To say "$Pc$ is not a tautological consequence of $\forall xPx$" only implies that that the logical relation between the propositions, whatever it is, is not settled by the distribution of truth-functional connectives in them.

Comment: :To say that Ax-> Pc is not a tautology,we need to accept that all 4 values for (u,v) including (1, 0) are possible.That could be only if u and v are independent?

Comment: No. In Enderton, tautology is used in the narrow sense to mean truth-table tautology. A logical truth need not be a tautology.

Comment: Still doubtful about the initial 'No'.Agree with rest.Ax-> Pc is not a tautology because (u, v) can take the value (1, 0).By making it a logical axiom,we are stipulating that (u, v) cannot take the value (1, 0) that is u is always  less than or equal to v.

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference between *tautological consequence* and *logical consequence* is related to the different "expressive capabilities" of sentential logic language compared to first-order one.

Consider a *tautology* like : $A \lor \lnot A$.

Every instance of it is *true*; thus, if we consider the instance obtained replacing the sentential letter $A$ with a f-o logic formula, like : $\forall xP(x)$, we still have a tautology :

> $\forall xP(x) \lor \lnot \forall xP(x)$.

As you can see in Enderton's book [see page 115 and **Exercises 3**, page 129] :

> If $\Gamma$ tautologically implies $\varphi$, then it follows that $\Gamma$ also logically implies $\varphi$. But the converse fails.

Consequently, every tautology is *valid*, but it is **not** true that every valid formula is a tautology.

Enderton's example [see page 115] discussed above amounts to show this fact.

For simplicity, I'll rewrite it using "tautology" and "valid", exploiting the fact that [see Enderton, page 99] :

> $\alpha \vDash \varphi$ **iff**  $\vDash \alpha \rightarrow \varphi$.

Consider now the f-o formula : $Pc \rightarrow \forall xP(x)$.

If we "read it" as a formula of sentential logic [see discussion at page 114], it is composed of two distinct sub-formulae; thus we have to translate it using two different sentential letters.

What we get is : $A \rightarrow B$, which is **not** a tautology.

As you said, we can choose a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(A)=1$ and $v(B)=0$ and the result will be : $v(A \rightarrow B)=0$, exactly because the two sentential letters are independent.

Recall my first statement about the different "expressive capability" of the two languages : sentential logic is not able "to see" the interdependency between $Pc$ and $\forall xP(x)$.

Of course, the same argument applies to : $\forall xP(x) \rightarrow Pc$.

---

---

Consider now the f-o case; we need to extend the rules for "calculating" truth assignments.

We still have :

- $v(\lnot \varphi) = 1 - v(\varphi)$

and :

- $v(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) = max(1-v(\varphi), v(\psi))$

but we need also a rule for the universal quantifier ($\forall$) :

- $v(\forall x P(x))=inf [v(P(t/x))]$, where *inf* is "calculetad" taking into account all $t$.

Again, we say that $\alpha$ is *valid* **iff** $v(\alpha)=1$, for all $v$.

---

*a)* : $Pc \rightarrow \forall xP(x)$

Consider an interpretation of the above formula in a *domain* where $P$ holds of $c$, but assume also that there are some elements in the domain such that $P$ does not hold of them.

[We can think at the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* as domain of the interpretation and interpret the predicate letter $P$ with the property $Odd(x)$, and assume that the constant $c$ denote the number $1$. Clearly $Odd(1)$ is true, but $Odd(2)$ is not.]

Using this interpretation to define a truth assignment $v$, we have that :

$v(Pc)=1$, while $v(P(t/x))=0$, for some $t$;

thus :

$v(\forall xP(x))=inf [v(P(t/x))]=0$.

In conclusion :

> $v(Pc \rightarrow \forall xP(x))=max[1-v(Pc), v(\forall xP(x))]=max(0,0)=0$

and we conclude that the formula is **not** valid, and consequently :

> > $$Pc \nvDash \forall xP(x)$$

---

*b)* : $\forall xP(x) \rightarrow Pc$

Now we have two cases to consider :

*$b_1$)* : $P$ holds of every element in the domain of the interpretation. Thus, it holds also of $c$.

[Reusing the set $\mathbb N$, now we can interpret the predicate letter $P$ with the property $x \ge 0$, and again assume that the constant $c$ denote the number $1$. Thus : $\forall x(x \ge 0)$ and $1 \ge 0$ are both true.]

This implies : $v(P(t/x))=1$, for all $t$, and so also : $v(Pc)=1$.

Thus, $v(\forall xP(x))=inf [v(P(t/x))]=1$, and we have :

> $v(\forall xP(x) \rightarrow Pc) = max[1-v(\forall xP(x)), v(Pc)]=max(0,1)=1$.

*Note* : as you ca see, it is in this case that the truth values assigned by $v$ to $Pc$ and $\forall xP(x)$ are **not** independent of each other.

---

*$b_2$)* : it is not true that $P$ holds of every element in the domain of the interpretation.

[Consider now $\mathbb N$ with the property $x > 0$; $\forall x(x > 0)$ is not true, because $0 \le 0$.]

This implies : $v(P(t/x))=0$, for some $t$, and thus :

$v(\forall xP(x))=inf [v(P(t/x))]=0$.

Now, it does not matter whether $P$ holds of $c$ or not; we can calculate :

> $v(\forall xP(x) \rightarrow Pc) = max[1-0, v(Pc)]=max(1,v(Pc))=1$.

In both cases $v(\forall xP(x) \rightarrow Pc) = 1$ and we conclude that the formula is  valid, and consequently :

> > $$\forall xP(x) \vDash Pc$$