# Difference between Logical and Tautological equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I've googled already for an explanation and examples that show the difference between logical and tautological equivalences.
I understand that a tautological equivalence is first a logical one, but not necessary vice versa. Besides that as far as I've seen they are the same.
Are the truth tables the same? What could be a good example that shows the differences between both?
Thanks.

Examples of the questions I was given on this matter:
1)(pVq)->r is the tautological equivalence of (p->r)∧(q->r)
2)~p->(qVr) is the tautological equivalence of ~q->(pVr)
I have to demonstrate which one, if any of those two are true statements.

On this basis I have to understand the difference between tautological and logical equivalences, why one and not the other, both or none.

Comment: Please review [Tautological and logical consequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560826/tautological-and-logical-consequence?rq=1).

Comment: Who is using the terms, in which writing or speech, and in what context?

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of the two?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood There I edited it.

Comment: @MarkSaving I don't have them, that's what I'm asking. 
I edited and provided an example of the question though.

Comment: @amWhy I reviewed it, but I don't think it answers this question

Comment: If you don’t have the definitions, you should look in your textbook or ask the professor for the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a tautological equivalence is an equivalence *due to truth-functional considerations alone*. So, for example, a truth-functional analysis tells us that $A \land B$ is equivalent to $B \land A$. But note that that same truth-functional  analysis also tells us that $\forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x Q(x) \land \forall x P(x)$, so even though these expressions are first-order logic expression, it *already* is an equivalence on the basis of truth-functional considerations alone.

On the other hand, $\forall x P(x) \land \forall x Q(x)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$, but this equivalence cannot be established on the basis of a purely truth-functional analysis: you *also* need to understand the meaning of the quantifiers and how they work in order to see that these are equivalent. So, this would be an example of a logical equivalence, but that is not a tautological equivalence.

[Personal note: I have never understood why we use 'tautological' here ... why not 'truth-functional'?  I expect Mauro will know the (possibly historical) reason to this ...]